# Como inserir Weather Underground forecast icons

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, tkinter

Boa tarde

Estou a tentar inserir os icons do Weather Underground mas não aparece os icons em Python 3.
Abaixo deixo uma parte do código.

```
url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/api_Key/forecast/lang:PT/q/PT/Lisbon.json"

temp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

json_string = temp.read()

parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)

ico = parsed_json['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][0]['icon']

img = PhotoImage(ico)

label1 = Label(window, image=img)

label1.image = img

label1.pack()
```

Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: A requisição está sendo finalizada com sucesso? Você está definindo corretamente a *API KEY* para efetuá-la?

Comment: sim, a API Key está correcta, consigo ver as temperaturas e o resto, só os    icons é que não apareçem